# html input on codeigniter,

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I have HTML that uses bootstrap, it is written like this :

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3">PIB Ajuan</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
          <input name="pibaju" id="pibaju" class="form-control" type="text">
          <span class="help-block"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I  convert this so it uses the CodeIgniter's form helper https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html.

Comment: Please try to mark correct answer as accepted.

Comment: Try marking correct answer if you got it. @FadlyDzil

Answer (score 3):

It is simple:

```
<?php
$input_pibaju = array(
 "type" => "text",
 "name" => "pibaju",
 "id" => "pibaju",
 "class" => "form-control"
);
echo form_input($input_pibaju);
?>
```

instead of

```
<input name="pibaju" id="pibaju" class="form-control" type="text">
```

**EDIT:**
In your Controller, you have to call the *form_helper*, before you load the view file:

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

First you need to load form helper

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

Then you can use this

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3">PIB Ajuan</label>
  <div class="col-md-9">
      <?= form_input(['name'=>'pibaju','id'=>'pibaju','class'=>'form-control']) ?>
      <span class="help-block"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```